# Best way to accomplish knocked-out rule in CSS

Tags: css

Ive been handed a design that has a particular header with style the type knocking out a rule like:

```
------ Text Content ------
```

Ive done this a couple times over the years but i was never happy with my solution. Usually it involved using numerous elements. Since these are headers id like to keep the markup as lean as possible.

My first thought this time around was to use box collapsing to my advantage: http://jsfiddle.net/cEcCL/

However there a are few problems here:

1. This relies on setting the background of the `span` to something opaque in order to knockout the line. Problem is most of these will probably be in the upper portion of the page where the gradient background hasnt yet faded to its solid
2. Actually i wasnt aware of this till i made the fiddle - the text seems slightly off center, not sure why that is.
3. While it can probably be managed, Im worried about the robustness of the vertical offsets to center the line on the median of the text line-box.. What if i have long header that goes to 2 lines?

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not a perfect solution (I feel your pain here, this is a tough one), sometimes you can use `background-attachment:fixed` to remedy the background issue using the `<span>` technique if you are using a background image:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cEcCL/3/

```
<h2><span>Text Content</span></h2>
```

```
h2 span,
body{ /* Apply to h2 span and whatever the parent element is */
    background:url(background.gif) fixed;    
}
h2 {
    line-height: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
h2:after{
    content:" ";
    float:left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    margin-top:-15px;
}
```

Of course this only works if the parent element can have a **fixed** background **image**, and won't work with CSS3 gradient backgrounds. It's a limited-use idea, but I just thought I'd bring it to light.

It seems only `<legend>` tags have this behavior, and I know of no way to emulate that with CSS, and I don't think you don't want to start using `<legends>` for headings...

Comment: +1, Nice. I dont know why using :before/:after didnt cross my mind. This is fairly robust... i switched all the offsets over to em to i can adjust the font size easily.

Comment: Psuedo elements are always the first thing to cross my mind, it's almost like cheating. Yeah this code can get trimmed and you can switch to border-bottom on the h2 and relative position on the span instead of the `:after` content so you can support IE and whatnot. I was in mid-phase of trying this method when the background image thing crossed my mind, so this is like a mixed solution. Since you do need the span after all, might as well make the most of it.

Comment: Oh... big duh moment for me. I didnt realize till just now when i read you comment i really dont need the :after, i can just use my original method... the part that makes the fix is your hint on the background-attachment, and then my changes to em based offsets.

Answer (score 6):

[Here's a very quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/KjWK6/) that uses a single `h2` and the before/after pseudo elements.

```
h2:before, h2:after {
    content:' '; display:inline-block;
    height:0; width:100px;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0 1em
}
```

Obviously, there are some drawbacks:

- No IE6/7 support
- As it stands, you have to explicitly declare a width for the lines (but you might be able to mess with this)
- Doesn't handle multiple lines too well, but again, you might be able to edit the `h2` styles to make this work a little better

Comment: +1 Was thinking of something similar, without cheating and using a `<legend>`. I can't imagine any way to really get this to work perfectly, unless there's a way to emulate `<legend>` behavior with CSS... There's always the background issue (could be an image or gradient), and declaring fixed width for the lines is a pretty rough way to have do it.